# Programmatically check for a change in a class in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check for the size of a class in C#?

My reason for asking is:

I have a routine that stores a class's data in a file, and a different routine that loads this object (class) from that same file. Each attribute is stored in a specific order, and if you change this class you have to be reminded of these export/import routines needs changing.

An example in C++ (no matter how clumsy or bad programming this might be) would be
the following:

```
#define PERSON_CLASS_SIZE 8
class Person
{
  char *firstName;
}
```

...

```
bool ExportPerson(Person p)
{
  if (sizeof(Person) != PERSON_CLASS_SIZE ) 
  {  
     CatastrophicAlert("You have changed the Person class and not fixed this export routine!")
  }
}
```

Thus before compiletime you need to know the size of Person, and modify export/import routines with this size accordingly.

Is there a way to do something similar to this in C#, or are there other ways of "making sure" a different developer changes import/export routines if he changes a class.

... Apart from the obvious "just comment this in the class, this guarantees that a developer never screws things up"-answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not normally needed - most serialization libraries use reflection so changes automatically get persisted (though care needs to be taken with serialized types with different versions as serialization may fail if these change too much). See the `DataContractSerizlizer`, `BinaryFormatter` and `XmlSerializer` classes in the BCL. Protocol buffers are a third party option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each attribute is stored in a specific order, and if you change this class you have to be reminded of these export/import routines needs changing.

It sounds like you're writing your own serialization mechanism. If that's the case, you should probably include some sort of "fingerprint" of the expected properties in the right order, and validate that at read time. You can then include the current fingerprint in a unit test, which will then fail if a property is added. The appropriate action can then be taken (e.g. migrating existing data) and the unit test updated.

Just checking the *size* of the class certainly wouldn't find all errors - if you added one property and deleted one of the same size in the same change, you could break data without noticing it.

Comment: Jon you're my hero! Every time you post an answer/reply, it's always clear concise. Thanks for taking some much of your time answering our questions on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Jon: Yeah, I'm aware of the problems with just checking the sizeof a class. I guess the human factor in forgetting to update exporting/importing routines are things I just have to live with?

Comment: @OddBeck: Definitely not - unit tests can absolutely help here. You still have to do the work, of course, but with less risk: if you have a "golden" file which you deserialize in a test (and check the results), then you should be able to spot any breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

A part from the fact that probably is not the best way to achieve what you need,
I think the fastest way is to use [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). You can get the IL body of the entire class.